# User defined error in YACC

Tags: xml, bison, yacc, lex

I'm parsing an XML file using Lex and YACC.My grammar is like.

```
START_TAG attributes AN_CLOSE childelements data END_TAG AN_CLOSE 
{
    if(strcmp(getSubStr($1,1,strlen($1)-1),getSubStr($6,2,strlen($6)-1))==0)
        {
            //Here comes action to be performed if elements match
        }
        else
        {
            yyerror("Invalid Input File");
            //In such message should be printed and parsing should stop 
        }
}
```

where START_TAG, AN_CLOSE, END_TAG, and AN_CLOSE are tokens returned by lex file.
What each token identifies is given below:

```
START_TAG :<element 
AN_CLOSE : > 
END_TAG :</element
```

Now to check if input XML file is valid, I'm checking text of element' element' of START_TAG ie $1 with 'element' of END_TAG ie $6. In case if elements mismatch I have to print message and stop parsing. My error message is getting printed however parsing continues. Any suggestion on how to stop parsing would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`YYABORT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Parser-Function.html#index-YYABORT) macro, which will cause `yyparse` to return with status 1.

Comment: Thanks rici. If(){ 
        }else
        {
            yyerror("Invalid Input File");
            YYABORT; 
        } Working fine.